# converting back prediction values to original scale(forecasting with python arima model)

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, forecasting, arima

i m trying to do some forecasting with ARIMA model. I have a problem converting back my predictions to original scale. here is my code.
can someone help me find the error in my script? I woudl really appreciate it thank you.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

#arima model
model=ARIMA(ts_logscale,order=(2,1,2))
results_ARIMA=model.fit(disp=-1)
plt.plot(datasetlogdiffshifting)
plt.plot(results_ARIMA.fittedvalues,color='red')
plt.title('RSS: %.4f'% sum((results_ARIMA.fittedvalues-datasetlogdiffshifting["Chargé (T)"])**2))
print('plotting ARIMA model')
```

[image: PLOTING THE PREDICTIONS]

now, when i try to convert back:

```
#converting back
#creating a time serie
predictions_ARIMA_diff=pd.Series(results_ARIMA.fittedvalues,copy=True)
#convert to cumulative sum
predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum=predictions_ARIMA_diff.cumsum()

predictions_ARIMA_log=pd.Series(ts_logscale['Chargé (T)'].ix[0],index=ts_logscale.index)
predictions_ARIMA_log=(predictions_ARIMA_log).add(predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum,fill_value=0)
#plotting
predictions_ARIMA=np.exp(predictions_ARIMA_log)
plt.plot(ts,color='blue')
plt.plot(predictions_ARIMA,color='red')
```

[image: plotting predictions after converting back]

as u can see it s very different from first plot...

Answer (score -1):

ARIMA (2,1,2): is a model with two (2) autoregressive terms, one (1) back shift operator, and two (2) moving average terms. Now, when you apply one (1) back shift operator you don't have to worry because statsmodels models will convert back your predictions, so, the only problem here is the log transformation you did previously, for that, just use np.exp to your predictions and problem solved!

Comment: i have tried this 
predictions=np.exp(results_ARIMA.fittedvalues) but it s worse than before

Comment: @OumaymaRiahi you have to consider that when you use results_ARIMA.fittedvalues the back shift operator has already been taken out, so now the only transformation that left is the log one. That said, to transform your logarithmic back to normal you should apply np.exp.

How do you know that ARIMA(2,1,2) does a good fit to your data?

Comment: i ploted ACF and PACF

Comment: @OumaymaRiahi ACF and PACF for log transformed data or original data?

Comment: @Snedecor Both AR and MA terms can be written in terms of the backshift operator, so your description of the ARIMA(2,1,2) model (and in particular the part about the `d` parameter) is somewhat confusing. ARIMA(2,1,2) is a model that has 2 AR terms, 1 order of differencing, and 2 MA terms.